# Findall method in python

Tags: python, regex, findall

My code is looking for links containing 'i.imgur.com/'. How to make it search for both 'i.imgur.com/' and 'imgur.com/' ?. Here is the code:

```
import praw
from urllib import urlopen

def sub(path):
yy = r.get_subreddit(path).get_hot(limit = 10)
tt = urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/' + path + '/').read()
search = re.findall('http://i.imgur.com/\w+.\w+', tt)
```

Comment: You can make a part of your pattern optional by using the `?` quantifier. For example, `http://(?:i\.)?imgur\.com/\w+\.\w+` I recommend using a parser instead.

Comment: finding all imgur.com instances will also find all i.imgur.com instances

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for literal periods where you have them in this regex, so I escaped them.  Also, you should use raw strings when defining regular expressions in python (the 'r' before the string literal).  You can make part of a regex optional by enclosing it in parens and proceeding it with a question mark:

```
re.findall(r'http://(i\.)?imgur\.com/\w+\.\w+', tt)
```